# Why is sequelize metata undefined on raw query update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to run a raw MSSQL update query. The documentation for raw update queries states that the message for number of rows updated will be contained in the metadata. In the following function both results and metadata are undefined on update statements. It works perfectly fine if I use a normal select statement.

[Documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html)

The section in reference is the very first example.

Could someone help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

```
var query = 'UPDATE contacts SET aolid = 1 WHERE contactid =  804748'  

connection.query(query).spread(([results, metadata]) => {
        console.log(metadata)  // will log undefined
        console.log(results) // will log undefined
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use

```
.then(([results, metadata]) =>
```

or

```
.spread((results, metadata) =>
```

but `.spread(([results, metadata]) =>` will not work. See [`spread()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html).

Comment: This does resolve the undefined issue! Thank you, however, the metadata is simply an empty array. Should the number of affected rows not be in that data or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @TJSouthern According to the documentation, `results` should be an empty array. Is that not the case?

Comment: Results is an empty array but so is metadata. Both are empty. I checked the database to see if the update statement applied to the data and it did work there.

Comment: @TJSouthern well your previous runs were successful too when you were logging the wrong variables. It's very likely that there were just no rows updated this time around.